# Return value from dataset and show in messagebox

Tags: vb.net

How can I make my application in VB.NET to return single value using DataSet.

I have function:

```
Public Function checkIfDisabled(ByVal keys As String)
    Dim BoxboxDataSet As DreamApp.boxboxDataSet = CType(Me.FindResource("BoxboxDataSet"), DreamApp.boxboxDataSet)
    Dim BoxboxDataSetInstallsTableAdapter As DreamApp.boxboxDataSetTableAdapters.installsTableAdapter = New DreamApp.boxboxDataSetTableAdapters.installsTableAdapter()
    BoxboxDataSetInstallsTableAdapter.GetDataBy3(keys)

End Function
```

Which calls this query through Get Method:

```
SELECT        process
FROM            installs
WHERE        (`installkey` = @installkey)
```

I want to show MessageBox with returned value. Note that returned value will always be 0 or 1

Comment: Then do it...what's holding you back?

Comment: The thing holding me back is the missing piece of code. 
I have tried with:
`For each drRow as Datarow in BoxboxDataSet.Installs.Rows


DrRow("process") = something

Next`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you want your function to return a value 0 or 1. Right now your function is nor returning any values whatsoever. At the end of your function down an if statement to decide what value you want to return.

Public Function checkIfDisabled(ByVal keys As String) Returns Integer

Then just write a return statement that returns the values as integers.

Comment: My function should return 'process' which is a column in my Mysql table. How would I display query result?

Comment: What is the datatype in your column? And do you want to return all columns at once?

Comment: Thank you, i have figured it out based on your answer. Marked as a correct answer

Comment: Thank you! Glad to help!